# Log keypresses in both host (windows) and AWS workspace (ubuntu) to diagnose communication error

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, windows-11, amazon-web-services

My company uses AWS workspaces for our work VMs. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on the workspace ([a fairly recent upgrade](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-workspaces-introduces-ubuntu-desktops/) over their previous offering, Amazon Linux 2).

In order to use Ubuntu 22.04 on the workspace, you have to use the latest AWS workspaces client, which uses WSP ([Workspaces Streaming Protocol](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/wsp/)), rather than the previous protocol which uses PCoIP.

I am the first user in my company to use Ubuntu 22.04 on my workspace, and therefore the only user using WSP vs PCoIP.

My previous host machine was an Apple MacBook Pro, and it worked fine.

I recently changed to a Dell XPS 15 running Windows 11, and now occassionally some keypresses don't register on the workspace. Most notably `(` and `)` (which, as a programmer, I use a lot!). I don't see this behaviour when just using apps in Windows itself.

Also, I'm using the same external keyboard plugged into the same docking station that was used with both the MacBook Pro and the Dell XPS 15.

I have an International QWERTY keyboard, and initially found that Windows was suppressing some keys (eg the ` (grave accent) key, which is apparently because it then [allows special accent letters to be entered](https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/problem-with-the-grave-accent-key.298034/)). I subsequently changed the keyboard settings to US QWERTY layout, and so those keys are no longer initially suppressed.

So I'm assuming this isn't the cause of the problem.

My suspicion is that the keypresses are registering in Windows, and not in the AWS workspace client.

My idea is that I can run a keylogger application on Windows and on Ubuntu at the same time, and will be able to verify that the issue.

Is such software available, and if so, how can I use it?

Comment: Have you tried looking for another key combination to play brackets `()` in the AWS workspace? Play with it a bit. As an intuition it could be some setting of the AWS keyboard choice under windows. If you find that parentheses or other characters are mapped differently than you expect,  you may have some hints about where to direct your attention. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The thing is it's seemingly random - the parentheses do work most of the time, but every now and then even though I've pressed the key, they don't register. I then have to go back and press the key again, and that will insert it. Given I touch type, it's a complete disaster, and I often only notice when the code fails to compile!

Comment: Proceed by trial and error. Try another keyboard; for hardware problems it is not so significant that keyboard worked before: all things worked before breaking... If problem disappears, try cleaning the old keyboard. _Crumbs_ under the keys may prevent proper functioning. Check for contacts under problematic keys partially worn out. In case of different timing for catching keyboard interrupt between host and emulated OS. Emulated... have you tried if the problem occurs even if you work directly under Linux (with a system on USB)? If it works flawless the problem is in windows.

Comment: The keyboard works fine just on Windows, but not on the remote AWS workspace via Amazon's Windows WSP client. The keyboard works fine just on Mac, and on the remote AWS workspace via Amazon's Mac WSP client. So clearly the issue is in either Windows itself or in the Amazon Windows WSP client. Being able to prove to AWS support that the keys work in the host but not on the remote is the first step to opening a support ticket with them - hence asking for information on a keylogger approach